# Python IDLE hangs when opening/saving files

Tags: python, python-idle

I just downloaded the latest Python IDLE 3.2 for Windows 7 (64-bit).

I can open, edit, and save existing .py files, but if I open a new document and try to save it, IDLE hangs.

After a few attempts, I tried using a regular text editor to create a hello world program (plain ASCII).  But I cannot even open that file: IDLE hangs when trying.

I've searched the web and surprisingly found no hits for this problem.  Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: This was almost certainly a Python rather than IDLE issue as IDLE uses the the same open function that you can use directly.  In any case, the problem seems to be gone.  I just created `.../New folder/New text document.py` in Explorer and opened it from IDLE in both 2.7.11 and 3.5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears IDLE doesn't cope with paths that have spaces in them.  I worked around the problem by choosing directory paths that don't have spaces.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem on Win 7 64 bit. I am really surprised at this behavior. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @rafraf:  Not documented anywhere I've seen.